# Equality of functions in Scala, is functions objects in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am reading the book Programming in Scala. In the book, it says that "A function literal is compiled into a class that when instantiated at runtime is a function value". And it mentions that "Function values are objects, so you can store them in variables if you like".

So I try to check the equality between functions. But I failed.

1. If function is object in Scala, then it should behave like other objects in Scala. Maybe check equality of function is meaningless, so it is disabled?
2. And will function be compiled into object in Scala?

Comment: I was able to solve some of this problem domain. I have covered what I discovered and posted it as an answer to another related StackOverflow question. You can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34909554/501113

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium thanks, when I raised this question, what came to my mind was that if functions are objects in scala, then is it possible to define something like `equalTo` or `equals` to check the equality of two functions values(not limited to check equality of references). Now, it seems that it's only possible to check equality of references of function values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lambda are compiled as anonymous classes (not case class, as far as I remember). That means if you do:

```scala
val f1: (String) => String = _ => "F1"
val f2: (String) => String = _ => "F2"
```

Both `f1` and `f2` are subtype of `Function1[String,String]`, but they are of different anonymous classes, so can't equal.

If you write it as:

```scala
case class F(res: String) extends ((String) => String) {
  def apply(s: String) = res
}
```

Then:

```scala
val f1: (String) => String = F("A")
val f2: (String) => String = F("A")
f1 == f2 // true
```

Comment: But if I use following code: def f1(a: String): String = "F1"; def f2(a: String): String = "F2"; f1 == f2;. At the statement f1 == f2, I get the error: not applicable to (String). What's the difference between above code with yours?

Comment: Once again doing do you implement trait `Function[String, String]` by 2 differents anonymous classes. There is nothing thzt czn help the compile to know they are equal, semantically for you.

Comment: That's not the error I am getting. I get "`error: missing arguments for method f1;`" and "`error: missing arguments for method f2;`", which makes sense: you have defined two *methods* (not functions, functions and methods are totally different), `f1` and `f2` both of which take one argument of type `String`, but you are *calling* them with *no* argument and then try to compare the results of calling them.

Answer (score 8):

It's not clear what "equality" of functions means. Typically, what people care about is "do these two functions compute the same result?"

This, however, is a well-known undecidable problem, the *Function Problem*. The actual proof is more complex, obviously, but a simple intuition is: if you could tell whether two functions were equal, then you could solve the Halting Problem by asking "is this function equal to `while (true) {}`?"

So, we cannot decide whether two functions compute the same result. What we *could* do, is for example, check whether they contain the exact same code. But that is pretty boring. Just some tiny compiler optimization or renaming a single variable will make two functions that intuitively should be equal not equal.

Ergo, we take the easy way out: two functions are equal if they are identical, otherwise they aren't.

Comment: I think the "equality" about functions may be as: imagine functions as rules to map one value space to another value space, if two functions hold the same rule, then they are equal. But I think it's impossible for compiler to do that for now.

What I really get confused is that in my reply to applicius's answer, it's about the syntax and concepts of functions, methods in Scala.

Comment: "it's impossible for compiler to do that for now." – No, it is impossible to do that, period. Things that are proven to be impossible don't change with technology. The *Function Problem* is undecidable and it will stay undecidable until the end of time.

Comment: Thanks about Function Problem and explanations, and I think I need to review the concepts of functions and methods.

Comment: `while (true) {}` could be defined as having the unit type. So if we are only considering pure functions, the halting problem would be equivalent to `f(): Unit  = ()`. I wonder if this would make analysis of the equivalence of pure functions any simpler...

Comment: Why the unit type? Usually, diverging computation is defined as having the bottom type (or, rather, the bottom type is defined to be the type of diverging computation). Unit is the type for computations that return nothing, Bottom is the type for computations that don't return. If you know C, C++, Java, C♯, or similar languages, Unit is similar to `void`.