# function/method reference equality in scala

Tags: scala

Hello is it possible to check if a method/function reference is equal to another in scala? For example to write a function like the following and get true?

```
scala> def m = 1
m: Int

scala> def check(p: () => Int): Boolean = p == m _
check: (p: () => Int)Boolean              

scala> check(m _)
res0: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:**
Yes, it is possible to test for equality between two concrete function references in Scala, but not exactly in the way you stated your problem. You just have to capture the concrete function reference of an object, class or trait (not a lambda, anonymous function, etc.).

**Details:**
Because Scala does have the notion of a function reference, it is possible to check two different function references for reference equality. And because Scala also provides a mechanism for obtaining a function reference from any valid Scala method, it means you can likely do what you were seeking to do, given your comment question on m-z's answer, "...there is no way to get a reference or something similar for a method?"

The essential thing to remember is that two functions can only be checked for reference equality. IOW, to functions CANNOT be checked for function definition equality (which you don't really want anyway for the Pandora's box of undesired undecidable tangents it would generate).

So, below is how I came to think about it concretely and accurately. I used the Scala (2.11.7) Worksheet within IntelliJ (15.0.3) to create the following test scenarios.

First, the failure pathway, both compile time and run time:

```
object ConcreteMethods1 {
  def intToStringNone(string: String): Option[Int] =
    None

  def intToStringSome1(string: String): Option[Int] =
    Some(1)
}
//def someMethodFailureCompileTime(
//    parseFunctionReference: String => Option[Int]
//): (Boolean, Boolean) = {
//  (
//      parseFunctionReference == ConcreteMethods1.intToStringNone
//    , parseFunctionReference == ConcreteMethods1.intToStringSome1
//    )
//}
def someMethodFailureRuntime(
    parseFunctionReference: String => Option[Int]
): (Boolean, Boolean) = {
  val intToStringNoneFunctionReference: String => Option[Int] =
    ConcreteMethods1.intToStringNone
  val intToStringSome1FunctionReference: String => Option[Int] =
    ConcreteMethods1.intToStringSome1
  (
      parseFunctionReference == intToStringNoneFunctionReference
    , parseFunctionReference == intToStringSome1FunctionReference
  )
}
val someMethodNoneFailureRuntime =
  someMethodFailureRuntime(ConcreteMethods1.intToStringNone)
  //want (true, false), but get (false, false)
val someMethodSome1FailureRuntime =
  someMethodFailureRuntime(ConcreteMethods1.intToStringSome1)
  //want (false, true), but get (false, false)
```

Second, the success pathway (which implies both compile time and run time):

```
object ConcreteMethods2 {
  def intToStringNone(string: String): Option[Int] =
    None

  def intToStringSome1(string: String): Option[Int] =
    Some(1)

  val intToStringNoneFunctionReference: String => Option[Int] =
    intToStringNone

  val intToStringSome1FunctionReference: String => Option[Int] =
    intToStringSome1
}
def someMethodSuccess(
    parseFunctionReference: String => Option[Int]
): (Boolean, Boolean) = {
  (
      parseFunctionReference == ConcreteMethods2.intToStringNoneFunctionReference
    , parseFunctionReference == ConcreteMethods2.intToStringSome1FunctionReference
  )
}
val someMethodNoneSuccess =
  someMethodSuccess(ConcreteMethods2.intToStringNoneFunctionReference)
val someMethodSome1Success =
  someMethodSuccess(ConcreteMethods2.intToStringSome1FunctionReference)
```

And there you have it, testing equality between two concrete function references in Scala. This little trick helped solve a core issue with recursion I had trying to write generic parsing code which had a parsing from a string failover at root. I was able to use this concrete function reference equality trick to properly terminate the recursion.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as a reference to a method. When you write `m _` you are eta-expanding `m` to a function. A *new* instance of a function.

You *can* reference check functions (assigned to vals or vars), but by reference only.

```
def m = 1

val mx = m _
val my = m _ // not the same function as `mx` !
val mz = mx

scala> mx == mx
res4: Boolean = true

scala> mx == my
res5: Boolean = false

scala> mz == mx
res6: Boolean = true
```

`mx` is equal to itself (by reference), but while it is logically equivalent to `my`, it was created by a separate eta-expansion, and therefore does not have reference equality. `mz` on the other hand does hold the same reference as `mx`.

The bottom line is, comparing a newly eta-expanded method to another function will *always* yield false. Even if it is itself.

```
scala> m _ == m _
<console>:12: warning: comparing a fresh object using `==' will always yield false
       m _ == m _
           ^
res10: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Okay, I got it. So, to understand it completely, there is no way to get a reference or something similar for a method?

Comment: @fusion: You can't when using lambda functions. But you can when using case classes: `case class M(i: Int) extends (() => Int) { def apply() = i }; val f1 = M(4); val f2 = M(4); f1 == f2 ~> true`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25570400/390808