# How know which function was assigned?

Tags: scala, lambda, equality

If I have something like this:

```
def fn1(a:Integer)="1"
def fn2(a:Integer)="2"
val f=fn2 _
if( f== fn1 _) "1" else if(f==fn2 _) "2" else "other"
```

Always return "other". How to know in code which function was assigned to f?

Comment: In this particular case, `f(0)` uniquely determines whether it was `fn1` or `fn2`. Otherwise, I don't understand what you are asking. Extensional equality of functions is (in general) undecidable.

Comment: I want to know which function was assigned to f. The real case is not trivial like this so can't be solved evaluation the function

Comment: As I've mentioned above, extensional equality of general functions in Turing-complete languages is undecidable. When defining `f`, you are constructing a new function by eta-expanding the method `fn2`. No other object will ever be equal to this function, only `f == f` will return `true`, every other comparison will always yield `false`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I think he is asking about comparing function references, not the functions themselves.

Comment: @Tim As you can see in my answer, this is the only generally applicable solution that I could come up with. But this is kind-of boring an mostly pointless, because, obviously, you can always compare references, it's nothing specific about functions. `val a = new AnyRef; val b = new AnyRef` will also give you `a == a` (`true`) and `a == b` (`false`)...

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
def fn1(a:Integer)="1"
def fn2(a:Integer)="2"

val f1=fn1 _
val f2=fn2 _
val f=f2
f match {
case `f1` => "1"
case `f2` => "2"
case _ => "other"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since extensional equality on functions (roughly speaking: `f` is considered "equal" to `g` if and only if `f(x) == g(x)` for all valid inputs `x`) is in general undecidable, you have essentially just two choices:

1. To each function, attach some abstract description on which you can define a decidable equivalence relation. For example, you could construct symbolic representations of those functions, for which you could define intensional equality or some slightly stronger equivalence relation that approximates the extensional equality from below (can be arbitrarily difficult to implement, restricts the set of functions for which it works).
2. Use JVM-reference equality:

   ```
   val fn1: (Int => String) = a => "1"
   val fn2: (Int => String) = a => "2"
   val f = fn2
   println(if(f == fn1) "1" else if(f == fn2) "2" else "other")
   ```

   This outputs `"2"`. Note that this kind of equality is very "brittle", for example,

   ```
   val fn3: (Int => String) = a => "2"
   ```

   will not be equal to `fn2`.

Comment: Now that's getting interesting. Any mistakes anywhere?

Comment: At least, I don't see how it contradicts anything of what [was told here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570251/equality-of-functions-in-scala-is-functions-objects-in-scala). Jörg W Mittag even sketched the proof of why extensional function equality must be undecidable...

Comment: I suspect that if the asker knew what "extensional equality" is, he wouldn't need the question in the first place, so expanding that would be useful.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov True. But I just wanted to throw in a few keywords that the OP could google (if he wanted). I didn't want to spend too much time on definitions and explanations, because I suspected that the OP wants equality on references anyway, because everything else would get rather complicated rather quickly. Anyway, added a really brief explanation in the introduction, just to emphasize that there are other meaningful notions of "equality" for functions.

Comment: I like how this answer starts: [Extensional equality in Turing complete programming languages is undecidable in general](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14132/is-it-possible-to-compute-whether-two-functions-are-extensional-equal).

Comment: The difference is that there the notion is already mentioned in the title of the question, so can be reasonably assumed the asker knows about it.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Sorry, didn't intend to notify you, I was just collecting related links, just in case I need it sometime in the future.