# Is there any way to match(switch case) lambda expression in Scala?

Tags: scala, lambda

I have code like this:

```scala
   def fn(operatorType: (Int, Int) => Boolean) {
      operatorType match {
         case ((Int, Int) => _ == _)  => //dosomething
         case ((Int, Int) => _ > _)  => //dosomething
      }
   }
   fn((a: Int, b: Int) => a > b)
   fn((a: Int, b: Int) => a == b)
```

Is it possible to know what kind of Boolean expression has been passed to the method ? Or are there any better ways to achieve this same logic ? I have to strictly keep the method to one argument which is lambda expression.

Comment: No, there is not _(simple)_ way to match which function it was passed to your function. The simplest solution is to have some **ADT** representing your operations, you then pass one of the instances of the **ADT** to your method, which you can pattern match to perform you desired operation.

Comment: Does [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570251/equality-of-functions-in-scala-is-functions-objects-in-scala), in particular [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25581222/2707792) cover your question? Your question currently looks like an XY-problem. If you were really bored, you could try to do something with macros, but that would probably be very brittle, because the problem is undecidable in the general case. So, what did you attempt to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example suggested by @LuisMiguelMejiaSuarez:

```
sealed trait Op extends ((Int, Int) => Boolean)
case object Equal extends Op {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int): Boolean = a == b
}
case object GreaterThan extends Op {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int): Boolean = a >= b
}
case object LessThan extends Op {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int): Boolean = a <= b
}
case object NotEqual extends Op {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int): Boolean = a != b
}

def fn(operatorType: Op) = 
  operatorType match {
    case Equal  => //do something with Equal.apply
    case GreaterThan => //do something with GreaterThan.apply
    case LessThan => //do something with LessThan.apply
    case NotEqual => //do something with NotEqual.apply
  }

fn(Equal)
```